# How to show only one textbox insted of two when using before method of jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I applied a textbox using before method of jquery to one of my wordpress page. But the issue is that it is showing two textbox instead of one. I want to show only one textbox. This is my code below

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(".product-listing-table").before("<p><input type='text' placeholder='search product by name, status, sku' id='upen'></p>");
```

[image: This is here]

Comment: I am using this code

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(".product-listing-table").before("<p><input type='text' placeholder='search product by name, status, sku' id='upen'></p>");

Comment: Add the code to the question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36431964/edit) button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this**

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // This will remove the serach_input
  $(".search_input").remove();
  $(".product-listing-table").before("<p class="search_input"><input type='text' placeholder='search product by name, status, sku' id='upen'></p>");
});
```